# Como ajustar a arma para que ela sempre atire onde a mira está

Tags: unity3d, jogos, unity-5

Tenho uma arma que está posicionada na tela manualmente e preciso criar um script de tal forma que quando eu atirar, a bala atingirá o ponto onde a mira está mirando, que no caso é a coordenada da metade da tela.

Queria também saber como faço para posicionar a arma (via script) para que o cano fique alinhado com a mira.[image: Imagem ilustrativa do desejado]

Comment: Você dá o tiro como? Você cria a bala a partir da arma ou a partir do personagem? Caso use um raycast, você faz ele partir da arma ou do personagem? É importante se certificar que o vetor de direção que a bala segue é normal em relação a câmera e que seja o mesmo do alinhamento do cano da arma.

Comment: Ela não atira, ainda. Eu pensei em instanciar a bala a partir da arma de maneira que ela saia pelo cano, como na realidade acontece. Pensei que se o script alinhasse apenas o cano da arma, de maneira que ele foque na mira, ao instanciar a bala ela apenas seguiria o vetor de direção do cano. Isso funcionaria? A bala atingiria o ponto central da tela independentemente da distância que o target está?

Comment: Michael, geralmente não vale a pena instanciar um objeto para ser a bala, isso consome recursos do jogo e ela vai se mover tão rápido que o jogador mal vai vê-la. Por isso o recomendado é usar um raycast, que basicamente traça uma linha invisível e verifica se ela colide com os outros objetos do cenário.

Comment: @JúlioNeto É porque eu pensei em fazer um rastro de projétil igual vemos nos jogos de FPS, como a fumaça de um projétil de bazuca, por exemplo.

Answer (score 2):

Faz tempo que não mexo com Unity3D, mas acho que dá para fazer isso usando a função [`Physics.Raycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html).

A solução seria fazer a arma sempre mirar para o ponto que se encontra bem a frente do atirador antes de você disparar o projétil:

```cs
 RaycastHit hit;
 bool bloqueado = Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out hit);
 arma.transform.LookAt(bloqueado ? hit.point : transform.forward);
```

Depois disso, você cria o projétil, usando o mesmo `Quaternion` de rotação da arma e posiciona-o bem na ponta dela.

Comment: "LookAt" não seria mais bem aproveitado?

Comment: @Matheus De fato, eu disse que fazia tempo que não mexia com isso. ;D - Resposta editada.